# How to remove StyleCop warning "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously" without removing async from signature

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, stylecop

Parent object and most children have async and use await.
StyleCop is watching and throwing a fit over lack of await in one child class.

What is the best way to make StyleCop happy when you can't remove the async signature?

For example:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var t = DownloadSomethingAsync();

     Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
  }

  public delegate Task<string> TheDelegate(string page);

  static async Task<string> DownloadSomethingAsync()
  {
     string page = "http://en.wikipedia.org/";

     var content = await GetPageContentAsync(page);

     return content;
  }

  static async Task<string> GetPageContentAsync(string page)
  {
     string result;

     TheDelegate getContent = GetNotOrgContentAsync;
     if (page.EndsWith(".org"))
     {
        getContent = GetOrgContentAsync;
     }

     result = await getContent(page);

     return result;
  }

  static async Task<string> GetOrgContentAsync(string page)
  {
     string result;

     using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
     using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
     using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
     {
        result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     }

     return result;
  }

  static async Task<string> GetNotOrgContentAsync(string page)
  {
      return await Task.FromResult("Do not crawl these");
      // removing async will cause "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>'
  }

}
```

Found the solution -- creating this for google searching to find easilly.

You can also use warning suppression as mentioned over here: [Suppress warning from empty async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155692/suppress-warning-from-empty-async-method)

// edit to remove debate about logging, which the question was not about in any way and was just for an example.

// edit to force async required because that confused people

Comment: Why is the method `async` then? If you are not going to await the return, then don't use the async modifier.

Comment: A second point based on your comment that you are logging something. Use a proper logging framework, they are not trivial things to build yourself and you won;'t need to worry about the async side of things at all.

Comment: `async` is not part of the signature. From the outside nothing knows whether you used `async` or not, just that it returns a `Task` or some `Task<T>`.

Comment: @DavidG I wonder where you read that the OP is not using a *proper logging framework* ?

Comment: @huysentruitw Logging frameworks tend not to use async methods.

Comment: @huysentruitw Because logging frameworks usually do all that for you, without worrying about async.

Comment: @huysentruitw and that's why I said to remove the async modifier...

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, if it's not supposed to be `async` then don't make it `async`, it's as simple as that really and "working around" is just misusing a system for the sake of compensating a poor implementation. `async` is nothing more than a keyword which tells the compiler to compile your code as an `IAsyncStateMachine`, as Jon says it does not form any part of the method signature. Method signatures comprise the name, return type, parameters, and access modifier.

Comment: Removed logging comment and forced async to be in signature.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not `await` anything, then simply remove the `async` keyword from the method declaration and return [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```cs
public override Task DoMyThing()
{
    // ..
    return Task.CompletedTask; // or Task.FromResult(0); in pre .NET Framework 4.6
}
```

Because the virtual method in the base class is marked as `async` doesn't mean the override needs to be marked as `async` as well. The `async` keyword is not part of the method signature.

Comment: Also worth noting that this [changes the semantics of the method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), particularly around how exceptions are handled.

Comment: Is it worth noting? I never thought about that but it makes sense that exceptions are thrown differently, but in the end, in both cases the exception is thrown, bubbles up and contains exactly the same call-stack, right?

Comment: Without `async`, the exception is thrown directly and synchronously; with `await`, the exception is captured and placed on the returned `Task`. The call stack is (essentially) the same; but the propagation is different.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

Add a bit of code in your async function:

```
return await Task.FromResult("Do not crawl these");
```

Suppress across project:

```
#pragma warning disable 1998
```

Or suppress on one method:

```
#pragma warning disable 1998
async Task Foo() {}
#pragma warning restore 1998
```

Comment: Why would you await `Task.FromResult(0)` and not just return it?

Comment: If you really want to use this hack, at the very least replace with `await Task.CompletedTask;`, to avoid a useless task creation

Comment: Some places block code checkin until all StyleCop warnings are resolved. If you are in a method that has async, StyleCop forces an await even if the method is empty.